# VS2013 forcing me to use MVC5 instead of MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Just to be clear - I want to use MVC4, not MVC5.

What happened today is that I can't add MVC 4 items to my project, only MVC 5.

Right click on Controllers > Add > Controller - here I see only WebAPI 2.0 options, no MVC.

Right click on Controllers > Add > New Item - there is no MVC4 option, just MVC with MVC5 options (page, partial, layout...)

In `packages.config`, I see the following:

```
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="4.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.1.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="2.0.20710.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

`Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` is of version `4.0.20710.0`, so it should be MVC4.
In project file (backed by change in .sln) I tried manually adding project type guid `E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47` (MVC4), but as soon as I reload project, VS2013 reverts it.

How can I use MVC4 in my solution again?

Comment: Downgrade to VS2010 :-)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: this is not an option. VS2013 must be used. However, if really neccessary I could upgrade to MVC5. But there is a lot of nugget packages installed in the project, upgrade could be quite painful and current timeframe virtually disallows that. So I would really like to avoid it.

Comment: Just found out that if I want to use DevExpress controls (now mandatory for my project) without problems, I have to work with MVC4. So, VS2013+MVC4 is a must.

Comment: Is this a new project? You can create MVC4 projects by selecting "Web" -> "Visual Studio 2012" -> "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application". Selecting "Web" only will use the MVC5 template.

Comment: @shoe: no, old project. I'd have to recreate a lot of stuff :(

Comment: Have you tried adding a new MVC4 project to the solution, creating the controllers there and dragging them into the controllers folder of your real project?

Comment: @Fred: yes, that works. As well as creating them manually or copy/pasting old controllers. However, it means no MVC4 support from devenv.

Comment: Did you see this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/793578/cant-create-an-mvc4-project-in-visual-studio-2013-preview#

Comment: @Fred: sorry, that wasn't the case. I didn't have the problem pointed out by that issue.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short: I couldn't do it. I had to re-create everything from scratch.

M$ really screwed up this.